# AWS Lambda and NLTK: Resource wordnet not found

Tags: aws-lambda, nltk

I know this question is been answered in many places but unfortunately none of the solutions mentioned are working for me. So I am detailing my challenge here:

I had written a local Python program with the following imports, which works very well. After the first download of the nltk data, I had basically commented out the last 3 lines.

```
import nltk

logging.info(nltk.data.path)

from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

nltk.data.path.append("/tmp")

nltk.download("wordnet", download_dir = "/tmp")

nltk.download("omw-1.4", download_dir = "/tmp")
```

Later I had copied the nltk package and nltk data as nltk_data, zipped and uploaded to lambda function whose architecture is x86_64:

[image]

[image]

When I upload to lambda function and test the function, I am receiving the following error message:

**Resource wordnet not found.**

I had googled and tried different options to solve the challenge:

1. Renamed the path in NLTK's data.py
2. Creating an environmental variable in lambda function
3. Trying to download nltk data while running the lambda function. This will not work, as we do not access to/from internet.
4. I had downloaded complete NLTK data and tried.
5. I had tried different python versions in AWS Lambda.

Can you please let me know, if there are any options which I haven't tried or If I am doing any mistake.

Thanks for your support in advance.

Regards,
Chaitanya

Answer (score 0):

the path append should point to your copied `/nltk_data/` location

```
nltk.data.path.append("YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT_FOLDER/nltk_data")
```

Or if you are using Docker's ENV you should have something like this:

```
ENV NLTK_DATA=YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT_FOLDER/nltk_data
```